# TextChanged events from Textbox don't come in order

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, textbox

I am trying to dynamically filter data based on a number entered into a TextBox as the user types in characters.  I am finding though that the text values seem to come out of order and I have no idea why.  For example, if the textbox already has "1379" in it and I then type in "2019" after that (so finishing with "13792019"), I am getting the following:

```
    TxtFilter_TextChanged; text 13792; Time: 637865675822596714
    TxtFilter_TextChanged; text 1379201; Time: 637865675846017202
    TxtFilter_TextChanged; text 13792019; Time: 637865675847734984
    TxtFilter_TextChanged; text 137920; Time: 637865675849383373
```

I am logging the Time in Ticks.  I can definitely see that the values are increasing, but I have no idea why/how "137920" is coming in after "13792019"?  I can consistently reproduce this.

Right now, I cause the postback to happen on keyup so that I can set the focus back on the textbox.  On OnFocus, I am setting the cursor to the last position (otherwise it goes back to the start).  I'm open to better ways of doing this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RefreshUpdatePanel(e) {
    __doPostBack('<%= txtFilter.ClientID %>', '');
    document.all.txtFilter.focus();
};

function SetEnd(txt) {
    if (txt.createTextRange) {
        //IE  
        var FieldRange = txt.createTextRange();
        FieldRange.moveStart('character', txt.value.length);
        FieldRange.collapse();
        FieldRange.select();
    }
    else {
        //Firefox and Opera  
        txt.focus();
        var length = txt.value.length;
        txt.setSelectionRange(length, length);
    }
}
```

Codebehind:  The LoadOrderList method binds the data based on the filtered text, and then loads the order info for the first item selected, if any.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        txtFilter.Attributes.Add("OnFocus", "SetEnd(this);");
        txtFilter.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "RefreshUpdatePanel();");

        LoadOrderList();
    }
}

protected void TxtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TxtFilter_TextChanged; text {0}; Time: {1}", ((TextBox)sender).Text, dtNow.Ticks));
    LoadOrderList();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe postback event order is guaranteed.  And in any case do you really want to do a postback on every keyup?  maybe use the blur event, wait for all the text and postback once.

Comment: Yes, the users want to see the results being filtered as they type.  I would have preferred to do it the other way as you said.

Comment: setting the cursor position is very quirky, especially across browsers.  You might try removing " txt.focus();" to see if that helps.

Comment: Ouch! And with update panels, double ouch.  Maybe consider posting back after collecting a few keystrokes, filtering a single letter is likely to produce a large dataset.  Also consider return only the top X rows.

Comment: Agree with fnostro; only run a search if the user hasn't typed anything in the last 500 milliseconds; relevant search term would probably be "debounce"

Comment: I would not do a full page post-back here. You need to do a web API call, pass the text box, get the response back.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do a full page post-back here. You need to do a web API call, pass the text box, get the response back. Do you have use of the ajaxtoolkit? It has a auto complete pre-built, and lets you set the timing/delay, and even number of characters you have to type.

Now, I might not want to adopt the whole ajaxtoolkit for this ONE feature, but I certainly would consider the tool kit - as the autocomplete does work well, and auto magic wires up the ajax calls for you - without a page post back.

And it easy to use.

You also get mult-select combo boxes, a really slick dialog box (easier then bootstratp, or jquery.ui ones to use). And you get to VERY nice up-loaders.

So, consider the ajaxtoolkit. It is certainly and somewhat dated, but if your project is still web forms, then I would consider adopting the tool kit, since then you can a working auto-complete example and tool - one that been battle hardened an one that you know just works well.

In fact, note ONE BIG ELEPHANT in the room here?

What is it?

Why of course no one was willing to post THEIR working example, and suggest/have show what they use for this VERY common task and feature.

And since no one is posting examples, then it VERY much means the time and effort to setup such and example is MORE TIME then what it takes to post on SO.

And if the time taken to show such an exmaple is MORE then what it takes to post on SO as  simple answer?

You ALEADY FAILED!!! - in other words, you want this kind of feature not only now but what about the next 10 examples you want to do this again? and again???

So the REAL goal, the REAL answer?

Regardless of WHAT  and WHICH road you take, you MOST CERTIANLY want to go down a road in which a working solution can be used over and over.

So, say I want to search for some hotel names. So, drop; in a text box, then click on the ajax tool kit extender.

So, I dropped in a text box, and then go:

[image]

Now, select auto complete

[image]

So, now my markup is this

```
    <font size="4">Search for Hotel : </font>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="250px">
    </asp:TextBox>  

        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
            ID="txtHotel_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
            BehaviorID="txtHotel_AutoCompleteExtender" DelimiterCharacters="" 
            ServiceMethod = "GetHotels"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1"
            TargetControlID="txtHotel">
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

And the code behind? This:

```
    [WebMethod()]

    public static List<string> GetHotels(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<string> Hotels = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))                
        {
            string strSQL 
                = "SELECT HotelName FROM tblHotels " +
                   "WHERE HotelName like @SearchText + '%' " +
                   "ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL,conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchText", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = prefixText;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                        Hotels.Add(sdr["HotelName"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return Hotels;
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

And you get a whole property sheet - you can customize the dealy, prefix length - all the setting and setup is done for you.

so, you have these settings:

[image]

So, there "are" existing tools for this.

But I think MUCH MORE then just going out and picking any old tool?

The real deal, the real issue?

Do you have a tool that lets YOU SPEND THE TIME here on SO to answer a question, to show a working example???

The fact that no one else is willing to do this?

It does not mean they are mean people, bad people, or even lazy people.

But it DOES mean they not picked a solution that gives you wizards, helpers, and built in UI designers that ALLOWED me to do all this work - in near record time, since I used a VERY easy solution.

Comment: Not so sure the OP is displaying a list... they wouldn't have to set cursor position for that.  Seems like they are auto-suggesting inside the text box... (which is much more of a pain to implement)

Comment: Well, it does auto suggest as you type - the so called "list" is automatic created for the text box - this is how say google works - start typing in, you see a match list appear below. So, Google is quite common used by people, and its "concept" of auto-complete does show a list below.  So, I guess it depends on what kind of auto complete - but your point is fair - the ajax autocomplete add-in works much like google does, and some obviously don't show the list below, but just show results in the text box. Jquery.UI (from same jQuery folks) ALSO has the list below. So, most display list below.

Comment: yeah, not really sure what the expected behavior is here... because the OP is using setSelectionRange it seems like they're doing something more like gmail where the suggestion appears in the text box as you type.  It's a bit unclear from the post.  If it is a standard list type then they should only need .focus().